# Cannot assign address of variable defined in linker script

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, arm, gdb, qemu

I found a solution, although I don't understand what went wrong.  Here is the original question.  The solution is at the end.

---

I am following this [Raspberry PI OS tutorial](https://jsandler18.github.io) with a few tweaks.  As the title says, one assignment appears to fail.

Here is my C code:

```
extern int32_t __end;
static int32_t *arena;

void init() {
    arena = &__end;
    assert(0 != arena); // fails
    ...
```

The assert triggers!  Surely the address shouldn't be 0.  `__end` is declared in my linker script:

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
    /* Starts at LOADER_ADDR. 0x8000 is a convention. */
    . = 0x8000;
    __start = .;
    .text : {
        *(.text)
    }
    .rodata : { *(.rodata) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    /* Define __bss_start and __bss_end for boot.s to set to 0 */
    __bss_start=.;
    .bss : { *(.bss) }
    __bss_end=.;
    /* First usable address for the allocator */
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __end = .;
}
```

Investigating in GDB (running it in QEMU):

```
Thread 1 hit Breakpoint 1, init () at os.c:75
75      arena = &__end;
(gdb) p &__end
$1 = (int32_t *) 0x9440
(gdb) p arena
$2 = (int32_t *) 0x0
(gdb) n
76      assert(0 != arena);
(gdb) p arena
$3 = (int32_t *) 0x0
```

GDB can find `__end` but my program cannot?

Here are a few other things I tried:

- the tutorial's code works without an issue (implying that QEMU and the ARM compiler are working)
- the assertion still fails when running without GDB (implying GDB is not the issue)
- I am able to assign `0xccc` to `arena` (implying arena is not the issue)
- I am not able to assign `&__end` to a local variable (implying `&__end` is the issue).

As requested in the comments, this is how I tried to assign to a local variable:

```
void* arena2 = (void*)&__end;
assert(0 != arena2);
```

The assertion fails.  In GDB:

```
Thread 1 hit Breakpoint 1, mem_init () at mem.c:77
77      void* arena2 = (void*)&__end;
(gdb) p arena2
$1 = (void *) 0x13
(gdb) p &__end
$2 = (int32_t *) 0x94a4
(gdb) n
78      assert(0 != arena2);
(gdb) p arena2
$3 = (void *) 0x0
(gdb) p &__end
$4 = (int32_t *) 0x94a4
```

- `assert(0 != &__end);` succeeds (implying `&__end` is not the issue?)

N.B. This version of `assert` is not the same as the one in `assert.h`, but I don't think it causes the problem. It just checks a condition, prints the condition, and goes to a breakpoint.  I can reproduce the issue in GDB with the assert commented out.

N.B.2. I previously included the ARM assembly of the C code in case there was a compiler bug

---

My solution is to edit the linker script to:

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
    /* Starts at LOADER_ADDR. 0x8000 is a convention. */
    . = 0x8000;
    __start = .;
    .text : {
        *(.text)
    }
    . = ALIGN(4096);
    .rodata : { *(.rodata) }
    . = ALIGN(4096);
    .data : { *(.data) }
    . = ALIGN(4096);
    /* Define __bss_start and __bss_end for boot.s to set to 0 */
    __bss_start = .;
    .bss : { *(.bss) }
    . = ALIGN(4096);
    __bss_end = .;
    /* First usable address for the allocator */
    . = ALIGN(4096);
    __end = .;
}
```

I don't understand why the additional `ALIGN`s are important.

Comment: As I understand __end already contains address of the end of the section as integer and it isn’t a variable at this address. Why do you try to get address of this address? Try to convert it directly to pointer: `arena = (int32_t*)__end;`

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov I gave that a shot despite the tutorial's using `&__end`.  The `0!=` assert succeeds, but the next assert fails.  In GDB, I see that the value assigned to arena is very large and crucially not the same as `p &__end` ... the smaller value seems right to me as it is close to the 0x8000 where the program begins

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov `__end`is a special symbol generated by the linker script. Only its address has a meaning. So the OP is correct to access the end address it needs through `&__end`

Comment: "I suppose this could be a compiler bug? " It's really the last hypothesis to consider :) Compiler bugs are not impossible but they are really rare.

Comment: Did you try a local variable `void *arena = (void *)&__end;`  This is how I am doing in my code and it works.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not able to assign &__end to a local variable"? How did you try this and what compiler errors or results do you get?

Comment: The assembler docs answer your side question about .align: for arm, the .align argument is the number of low-order zero bits which must be 0, so ".align 2" means "align to multiple of 4 bytes"  -- https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Align.html#Align

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean @thebusybee I updated the question to expand on using a local variable. TLDR the assignment happens, but it assigns 0... even though `&__end` has a non-zero address.

Comment: Could you have a look to the stack pointer when entering init function ?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean `info registers` says that `sp` is `0x7fd8` ... seems reasonable... growing down from the kernel?

Comment: In the gnu ld manual they usually use `extern char`.  Some CPUs have issue loading non-aligned addresses.  You have no alignment constraints in your linker file so it is possible that a linker decided that `arena = &__end;` with 'ints' doesn't work but `void*` would.  Also, you can add an `ALIGN` to your output section specifiers and then it will probably work properly.  Your aligns don't have to be a page size.  Just ALIGN(4) will probably be enough.  It is a good idea to do this anyways if you have a cache like the RPi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having here is because the "clear the BSS" loop in boot.S is also clearing some of the compiler-generated data in the ELF file that the C code is using at runtime. Notably, it is accidentally zeroing out the GOT (global offset table) which is in the .got ELF section and which is where the actual address of the __end label has been placed by the linker. So the linker correctly fills in the address in the ELF file, but then the boot.S code zeroes it, and when you try to read it from C then you get zero rather than what you were expecting.

Adding all that alignment in the linker script is probably working around this by coincidentally causing the GOT to not be in the area that gets zeroed.

You can see where the linker has put things by using 'objdump -x myos.elf'. In my test case based on the tutorial you link I see a SYMBOL TABLE which includes among other entries:

```
000080d4 l       .bss   00000004 arena
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 
000080c8 l     O .got.plt       00000000 _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
000080d8 g       .bss   00000000 __bss_end
0000800c g     F .text  00000060 kernel_main
00008000 g       .text  00000000 __start
0000806c g       .text.boot     00000000 _start
000080d8 g       .bss   00000000 __end
00008000 g     F .text  0000000c panic
000080c4 g       .text.boot     00000000 __bss_start
```

So you can see that the linker script has set __bss_start to 0x80c4 and __bss_end to 0x80d8, which is a pity because the GOT is at 0x80c4/0x80c8. I think what has happened here is that because you didn't specify explicitly in your linker script where to put the .got and .got.plt sections, the linker has decided to put them after the __bss_start assignment and before the .bss section, so they get covered by the zeroing code.

You can see what the ELF file contents of the .got are with 'objdump --disassemble-all myos.elf', which among other things includes:

```
Disassembly of section .got:

000080c4 <.got>:
    80c4:       000080d8        ldrdeq  r8, [r0], -r8   ; <UNPREDICTABLE>
```

so you can see we have one GOT table entry, whose contents are the address 0x80d8 which is the __end value we want. When the boot.S code zeroes this out your C code reads a 0 rather than the constant it was expecting.

You should probably ensure that the bss start/end are at least 16-aligned, because the boot.S code works via a loop that clears 16 bytes at a time, but I think that if you fix your linker script to explicitly put the .got and .got.plt sections somewhere then you'll find you don't need the 4K alignments everywhere.

FWIW, I diagnosed this using: (1) the QEMU "-d in_asm,cpu,exec,int,unimp,guest_errors -singlestep" options to get a dump of register state and instruction execution and (2) objdump of the ELF file to figure out what the compiler's generated code was actually doing. I had a suspicion this was going to turn out to be either "accidentally zeroed data we shouldn't have" or "failed to include in the image or otherwise initialize data we should have" kind of bug, and so it turned out.

Oh, and the reason GDB was printing the right value for __end when your code wasn't was that GDB could just look directly in the debug/symbol info in the ELF file for the answer; it wasn't doing it by going via the in-memory GOT.

Comment: thank you especially for including the tools and thought process in chasing down the bug

Comment: "Oh, and the reason GDB was printing the right value for __end when your code wasn't was that GDB could just look directly in the debug/symbol info in the ELF file for the answer" Kinda tricky ! Thank you